# How to retrieve data from current User in Firebase using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get current users firstname from firebase using swift code. Below is my JSON file and swift code. But it's not retrieving first name. Please suggest

[image: JSON structure]Json:

Swift code:

```
  if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser != nil{

        let queryRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("expatsappmembers")


        let userID : String = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!
        print("Current user ID is" + userID)

        queryRef.child("uid").child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
            print(snapshot.value)

            let userName = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["firstname"] as! String
            print(userName)


        })

    }
```

Comment: Comment that line and check What is console log for `print(snaphot.value)` check and add here

Answer (score 0):

It is slightly different to get a value from Firebase in Swift 3

the proper way to do it is:

```
ref.child("expatsappmembers").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

  // Get user value
  let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
  let firstName = value?["firstname"] as? String

  // ...
  }) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: I tried with your suggestion, but value of firstname is not retrieved.

Comment: @Sourabh please post the return of  `print(value)`, Place the code under `let first name = ....`

Comment: its not printing value!looks strange to me.

Comment: used below code, but still I am unable to get first name  in the label.

Comment: override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        
        if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser != nil{
        
            ref.child("expatsappmembers").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                
                // Get user value
                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                let firstName = value?["firstname"] as? String
                
                
                // ...
            })

Comment: { (error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

Comment: I have changed question.

Comment: @Sourabh, please use this code and post the return from the console...  `ref.observe(.value, with: {
            snapshot in
            
            let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
            print("Snapshot value:\n\n\(value)")
            
        })`

Comment: tried this code but it's not printing value to the console.  if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser != nil{
            
            let queryRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("expatsappmembers")
            
            
            let userID : String = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!
            print("Current user ID is" + userID)
            
            queryRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary; print(value) })}